# Freeze one or more grid columns

Tags: axapta, x++

Is it possible to freeze a grid column in Dynamics Ax so that as the user scrolls to the right the first column or two continues to show and doesn't scroll out of view?

Comment: How wide is your form? I would say that you could change the way you display your data if it is too wide. Perhaps add another grid below or take those fields out of the grid and show them above the grid and use them as a filter. It would all depend on what you are doing. Is this a system form or a custom form?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is not possible in Dynamics AX.

Comment: If this is really necessary to do you could try to emulate the behavior by using two grids that are side by side and share the same data source. One grid would have the frozen columns and the other would have the rest, but if there were enough records to require vertical scrolling then the vertical scrolling would not be linked for the two grids, which is defiantly not ideal.

Answer (score 0):

Since Excel solves this so easily, and exporting to excel (either csv or html) is quick and easy to do in Dynamics AX, I suggest you ask your client if it can be solved using Excel.

Yes. It involves some manual work after opening Excel. Not a perfect solution. ;-)